# PHP table from explode array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, html-table, explode

I have data like this:

```
something something_description, something2 something2_description, something3 something3_description...
```

And now I need with PHP to get table as:

```
<tr><td>something</td><td>something_description</td></tr>
<tr><td>something2</td><td>something2_decription</td></tr>
```

I don't know how many "something" and "something_decriptions" will it be so I need to set some loop.

for now I have this code:

```
$data = explode(',',$query);
```

from that I will get array like:

```
[0] => something something_description
```

Now how can I put this into table?

On net I found some examples for sorting array to table, but this is with one more "explode" inside "explode"

I could use some help.

Comment: explode, for loop, explode, print.

Comment: It seems you already have the answer: Loop through the array and explode the elements on `' '`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are looking for this:

```
    $data = explode(',',$query);

    echo '<table>';
    foreach($data as $row){
        echo '<tr>';
        $row = explode(' ',$row);
        foreach($row as $cell){
            echo '<td>';
            echo $cell;
            echo '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
echo "<table><tr>".implode("</tr><tr>",array_map(function($a) {return "<td>".implode("</td><td>",explode(" ",trim($a)))."</td>";},explode(",",$query)))."</tr></table>";
```

One-liner ftw :p