# showing explode data in html table

Tags: php, html, laravel

I want to show the data from this in each row of my html table, how do I do that?

```
<?php 
   $test = $object2->schoolname;
   $array =  explode(',', $test);
   echo $array[0];
   //print_r($myArray); --> output: Array( [0] => testSchool2  [1] => test)
?>
```

The only way I can think of is to use something like this:

```
<td>
            <input type="text" name='schoolname[]' value="<?php 
            $test = $object2->schoolname;

            $array =  explode(',', $test);
            echo $array[0];
       ?>" class="form-control"/>
 </td>
```

But I have to do it for every row, I want to show that if I have 2 datas inside the array, then 2 of the row must contain those data, I don't want to manually put in the array[0] like this. How can I do that? Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

My html table is based on this:
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dynamic-table-row-creation-and-deletion

Comment: read more about loops. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: @hassan I read about it already, I tried following here,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711175/php-table-from-explode-array, but still can't do it  since it is a dynamic table

Comment: The answer at the question you linked clearly states the same: Use a loop.

Comment: @commonsense yes it is similar, just that I am using a dynamic table, and I want to show the value inside is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean with "dynamic table"? What makes your table dynamic? Edit your question and show the tables code.

Comment: ... in my question, I already put in the link that I had used to make the table, https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dynamic-table-row-creation-and-deletion @commonsense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is loops.

```
foreach($array as $i => $value) {
    //code for each array item, as $value
}
```

eg

```
$test = $object2->schoolname;
$array =  explode(',', $test);

foreach($array as $i => $value) {
    echo "
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='text' name='schoolname[".$i."]' value='".$value."' class='form-control'/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    ";
}
```

There are a few different types of loops in php; for, foreach, while and do-while

Comment: but I am using a dynamic table as shown in this link, can the loop still even help? https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dynamic-table-row-creation-and-deletion

Comment: Why do you use dynamic tables when you fill them up from script? Dynamic rows are useful if you or user fill them up from front end or some kind of panel, but the code suggests the script does that for you.

Comment: I am doing an update now, so I would like to show the data that had been already entered @MichalSkrzypek

Comment: I think the loop answer is still valid. It should show the already entered data and still allow to add more rows. There should be no conflict there.

Comment: The loop does show the value but it is only showing the last part of the array, example, array[1] instead of array[0] @MichalSkrzypek

Comment: Impossible. There must be some kind of bug in your code. Please edit the question and update what you tried so I can have a look at your code.

Comment: Oh ok i found the error, it was the endforeach, I didn't close it, sorry for the careless mistake

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty basic foreach loop:

```
<table>
<?php foreach ($array as $value): ?>
    <tr><td><?= $value ?></td></tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: but I am using a dynamic table as shown in this link, can the loop still even help? https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dynamic-table-row-creation-and-deletion